# How to remove youtube logo from youtube player?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Hope you are doing well,
Im stuck at a point with youtube player , i dont want youtube logo to be displayed in my player.
At the same time the controls should be working , Is it possible any suggestions how to work out with this

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you are allowed legally to remove it nor you should.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = youTubeView;

int[] points = new int[]{0,0,4,0,0,3,0,1};

for( int i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    if( i == points.length-1 ){
        viewGroup.getChildAt(points[i]).setVisibility( View.GONE );
    } else {
        viewGroup = (ViewGroup)viewGroup.getChildAt( points[i] );
    }
}
```

Hope this will work!